# Польская инверсная запись

Tags: алгоритм, польская-запись

Какие есть алгоритмы, чтобы преобразовать стандартную математическую (инфиксную) запись в польскую инверсную?

Answer (score 1):

Да, на основе стека: [обратная польская нотация](http://algolist.manual.ru/maths/misc/revpn.php).